# VBA Coding Help - Checking Version

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I manage a Excel document that is loaded onto a SharePoint that approx. 60 users access each day.

The document has several references to other workbooks, at times I need to make changes to the references as well as normal changes in the document and I would like the ability for a VBA code that checks if the user is using the most current file version before allowing them to open the document.

I currently have a version number and date in 'V3.6 / 27-06-2018' format in a cell in the document. So ideally I could load another workbook on a share drive, reference that to match the cell (Hope that makes sense) - where the version doesn't match, a text box would appear advising the version is outdated and for the document to force close.

I am open to other suggestions if it makes it easier.

Comment: If they're opening it from Sharepoint then why wouldn't it be the latest version?

Comment: Which version of Excel is it? [365 has full-blown co-authoring support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104)

Comment: Hi Tim, I have found instances, where they are saving versions on their computers and use outdated versions. They are all in the habit of enabling macros for this document so not concerned with them disabling.

Comment: Hi Mathieu, I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: What you're suggesting (referencing a separate source for the current version information) seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is feasible if you write some codes in **Sub auto_open()** to compare the version in your shared workbook and the version stored in another place, say, an URL for a plain text file.

Comment: To answer @Tim 's comments : Maybe the users always download the Excel file and run it locally... So they wouldn't pay attention to the latest version.